# What protection does the /INTEGRITYCHECK MSVC linker option offer, if a malicious file without it can simply be substituted for the authentic file?

Tags: windows, digital-signature, c++

The [/INTEGRITYCHECK linker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/integritycheck-require-signature-check?view=msvc-170) sets a flag that "tells the memory manager to check for a digital signature in order to load the image in Windows". So  the general idea is that this ensures the binary is signed by a legitimate, trusted authority, before being loaded.

But this flag only exists in the binary itself, and not in an application that loads that binary. So if that binary is simply replaced with a malicious version of the same name that doesn't have this flag, a consuming application will just load that unsafe binary without asking questions.

So let's say I create a binary with this flag, called `myLib.dll`. Now, whenever I am linking to `myLib.dll`, I will only know if it is in fact the library I created by checking the digital signature. Now, this will only happen if the flag is set, and I can only *know if that flag is set* if it is in fact the library I built. So then what's the point of setting this flag in the first place?

I suppose setting this flag will still safeguard against the situation where the certificate of the signer has expired or where the signer isn't trusted. So as the developer you can prevent your binary from being run in those two cases. But what else does it do--what else is the purpose of this /INTEGRITYCHECK flag?